# Coloring the diff Output without using any predefined functions and using shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell

In Linux we have to color the output of  two files using the 'diff' command without using any predefined functions and the out put should be like:

diff file1 file2

> something(This should be in green color).

Answer (score 0):

To change color to green you can use

```
tput setaf 2
```

Try a google search for tput(1). Otherwise, but less correct, simply use echo to output ansi escape sequences, which are very standard, like:

```
echo -ne '\033[0;34m'
```